# How to combine Laravel Collections

Tags: laravel, collections, count

I want to combine the laravel collection into one if statement.The count and first should be in same if statement.

Can anyone help on this?

```
     if (EmailSave::where('email_id',$email_id)->where('user_id',$user_id)->count()< 1){  
                        $ableToSendMail = true;
                    }

          if (EmailSave::where('email_id',$email_id)->where('user_id',$user_id)->whereDate('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->addDays(30))->first()) { //mail sent again after 30 days
                        $ableToSendMail = true;
                    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using logical OR( `||` ) operator

```
  if ((EmailSave::where('email_id',$email_id)->where('user_id',$user_id)->count()< 1) || (EmailSave::where('email_id',$email_id)->where('user_id',$user_id)->whereDate('created_at', '>', Carbon::now()->addDays(30))->first())){  
                        $ableToSendMail = true;
   }
```

[PHP -> Logical Operators](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php)